# Detecting a 5 volt signal in serial port in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I am making an internet cafe software that is coin-operated. I want my program to detect 5 volt signal coming from a coin detector in every insertion of coin. However, I've been searching in google trying to find sample codes to do this but to no avail. Pinchange event doesn't do the trick since the wire that carries the signal is always connected to a serial port pin and pinchange event is always happening even without inserting a coin in the coin slot. I want to detect only the 5 volt signal that the coin detector sends to serial port in every insertion of coin. Please help me on this.

Thank you and best regards.

Answer (score 0):

I have several projects with similarities to this one. I would recommend using the .NET libraries for reading serial ports. In VB.NET it is something like:

```
Dim com1 As IO.Ports.SerialPort = Nothing 
com1 = My.Computer.Ports.OpenSerialPort("COM1")
Dim serialInput As String = com1.ReadLine()
```

The problem is the 5v signal. This is super easy to read with an Arduino or Raspberry Pi (the Raspberry Pi might be a better solution for you...RPi Foundation just came out with a new quad-core version...and it only runs like $40 and would have no problem surfing the web) to do the signal sensing.

You can get Arduino compatibles for less than $10 like this one http://www.adafruit.com/product/2000 and then program them to send whatever string you want to the serial port.

Good luck with your project.

Comment: Thank you for your idea. I am really considering to buy arduino uno(the only arduino I found here) but this costs Php 700 and coin detector costs Php 280. Since life is tough economically, I am finding a way to use the analog coin detector(sr-1228) to my project. Actually, there are two programs already made here(Philippines) but I am NOT impressed with security features and their support. They used only the pin 2 of the serial port connected to the wire that sends the coin signal nothing else.

Comment: Does the com1.Readline() reads the bytes coming from the input signal and convert it to string? Maybe I can get significant data from this code. I'll try this when I get home. Thanks